# Convert rows into columns by grouping one row value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

My table is like

```
CompanyName | DirectorName
ADS         | Rai
ADS         | Rao
ADS         | Raj
ADS         | Rio
SAS         | Josh
SAS         | John
```

But I want result like:

```
CompanyName | Director1 | Director2 | Director3 | Director4 
ADS         |Rai        |Rao        |Raj        |Rio  
SAS         |Josh       |John       |           |
```

For each company director name count varies. So kindly suggest how to form the data as per requirement dynamically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +  
                     QUOTENAME('Director' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() 
                                        OVER(PARTITION BY c.companyname 
                                             ORDER BY c.companyname) 
                                      AS VARCHAR(10)))
               FROM CompaniesDirectors c
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')  ,1,1,'');

SET @query = 'SELECT companyname,  ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                SELECT 
                  c.CompanyName, 
                  c.DirectorName,  
                  ''Director'' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() 
                                      OVER(PARTITION BY c.companyname 
                                      ORDER BY c.companyname) 
                                    AS VARCHAR(10)) director_num
                FROM CompaniesDirectors c
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                MAX(directorname)
                FOR director_num IN (' + @cols + ')
             ) p ';

EXECUTE(@query);
```

This should give you something like:

```
companyname    Director1    Director2    Director3    Director4
    AB            Foo          Bar           rr          tt
    ADS           Rai          Rao           Raj         Rio
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo<sup>1</sup>](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4e695/3)

<sup>1: <sup>Thanks to @bluefeet</sup></sup>

Comment: You don't need the full query when selecting the `@cols` you can just select from the table and in the `quotename()` use the `'Director' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.companyname ORDER BY c.companyname) AS VARCHAR(10)`

Comment: If you use `;` in sql fiddle for sql server, then you need to change the query terminator to `GO` -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4e695/3  Otherwise remove the `;` to get it to work

Comment: Thanks a lot. Query working as we expected. thanks once again